# What's the best way to wrap a Task as a Task<TResult>

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am writing some async helper methods and I have APIs to support both `Task` and `Task<T>`. To re-use code, I'd like the `Task`-based API to wrap the given task as a `Task<T>` and just call through to the `Task<T>` API.

One way I can do this is:

```
private static async Task<bool> Convert(this Task @this)
{
    await @this.ConfigureAwait(false);
    return false;
}
```

However, I'm wondering: is there there is a better/builtin way to do this?

Comment: whats the point of always returning false?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys To allow utility methods to always accept a `Task<T>` instead of having separate overloads to also support `Task`.

Comment: The point, I believe, is that he wants to be able to represent any `Task` as a `Task<T>`, and this is the simplest way he could think of.  I would probably use `Task<Unit>` instead.

Comment: Why aren't you doing the reverse? Typically you allow a `Task<T>` to masquerade as a `Task` (since it is one).

Comment: @Guvante Imagine writing `Task.WhenAll` and only accepting `Task` objects.  You then can't use the aggregation of the results in the continuation.  But if you've written `WhenAll` for `Task<T>`, it's basically the exact same code to write the version for `Task`, you just ignore the return value, thus you end up writing the method twice.

Comment: @Servy: I don't see a way of going from `Task` to `Task<T>` because you don't know what value to return (since there isn't one). You could define it as being `default(T)` but that would depend heavily on how you used the result. Since I have been playing with Haskell I could see using an applicative and `mzero` but there isn't anything direct that is similar in C#.

Comment: @Guvante The point would be to pass the `Task<T>` to some method that doesn't actually rely on the result at all, in the same way that `WhenAll` doesn't actually use the result, it just passes it along.  The code that then called `Convert` would then ignore the task's result, after calling that utility method.

Comment: @Servy: My point was mainly that a standard way of doing this is impossible because there is nothing to go off of. You cannot convert from a `Task` to a `Task<T>` without intimate knowledge of how the result is going to be used.

Comment: @Guvante You can use a result type that only has one value, i.e., `Unit`.  There's no practical difference between a `Task<Unit>` and a  hypothetical `Task<void>`, which is effectively what a non-future `Task` is.

Answer (score 6):

There is no existing `Task` method that does exactly this, no.  Your method is fine, and is likely about as simple as you'll be able to get.

Implementing the proper error propagating/cancellation semantics using any other method is deceptively hard.

Comment: I think we can get close to the proper error propagating/cancellation semantics (if not the same) with `task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22543052/1768303

Comment: @Noseratio That gives you proper error propagation, but not the proper cancellation propagation.

Answer (score 5):

**Updated**, the following propagates exceptions and cancellation:

```
public static class TaskExt
{
    public static Task<Empty> AsGeneric(this Task @this)
    {
        return @this.IsCompleted ?
            CompletedAsGeneric(@this) :
            @this.ContinueWith<Task<Empty>>(CompletedAsGeneric, 
                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously).Unwrap();
    }

    static Task<Empty> CompletedAsGeneric(Task completedTask)
    {
        try
        {
            if (completedTask.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                // propagate exceptions
                completedTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            // return completed task
            return Task.FromResult(Empty.Value);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            // propagate cancellation
            if (completedTask.IsCanceled)
                // return cancelled task
                return new Task<Empty>(() => Empty.Value, ex.CancellationToken);
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public struct Empty
{
    public static readonly Empty Value = default(Empty);
}
```

Comment: I would make that `Void` non-nested, so that you can actually write `Task<Void>` from the outside. Though something like `Unit` would probably be a better name, to not conflict with `System.Void` (which is the full name of `void`).

Comment: @svick, updated as suggested. I use `Empty` for this purpose in my projects.

Comment: @Noseratio: does this correctly propagate LogicalCallContext/execution context?

Comment: @ChaseMedallion, this fiddle confirms the execution context gets flowed, as expected: http://dotnetfiddle.net/Gc1sus

Comment: He cancellation isn't propagated as cancellation; cancelled tasks are turned into faulted tasks.

Comment: That's a *lot* of work to throw into trying to solve this problem, and as shown by all of the deleted answers and revisions/flaws in so many of them, I think it's pretty fair to say that there's a lot of value to the `await` solution, in that it's super simple, correct, and just doesn't have that margin for error when it comes to ensuring proper semantics.

Comment: @ChaseMedallion, you may want to check my update, specifically the part about `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: @Noseratio: thanks for the update! Since I am working in ASP.NET where a lack of ConfigureAwait(false) can cause deadlocks, I tend to use it very aggressively even when it's not technically required.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same requirement recently and I solved it with my own helper extension method, which allows the user to effectively wrap a `Task` with a `Task<T>`:

```
public static async Task<TResult> WithCompletionResult<TResult>(
    this Task sourceTask,
    TResult result
)
{
    await sourceTask;
    return result;
}
```

In your example call with:

```
Task<bool> task = myTask.WithCompletionResult<bool>(false);
```

If the result of `Task<T>` does not matter, I will use:

```
Task<object> task = myTask.WithCompletionResult<object>(null);
```

I hope this helps. If anyone knows of a pitfall with this approach let me know!

Answer (score -1):

Using `await` seems a bit overkill here.  No need for the state machine here, just use a `ContinueWith`

```
private static Task<bool> Convert(this Task @this)
{
    return @this.ContinueWith(p => { p.Wait(); return false;});
}
```

Note: This will result in an `AggregateException` being wrapped unfortunately

Comment: If the source task throws an exception or is cancelled that isn't propagated to the new task.  Using `await` *does* actually add value.

Comment: You've now wrapped the exception, if there is one, into an aggregate exception *twice*.

Comment: await will be faster than ContinueWith

Comment: @CoryNelson What makes you say that?  How do you think `await` is implemented?  (Hint, it attaches a continuation to the task.)  `await` will be a tad slower, due to the creation of the state machine, some extra error propagating semantics, etc.  Some of that is needed (i.e the error propagating semantics) some of it is not (i.e. the state machine).